# Isn't that code in tail recursive style?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I'm kinda new to Scala trying it out while reading Beggining Scala by David Pollack.
He defines a simple recursive function that loads all strings from the file:

```
def allStrings(expr: => String): List[String] = expr match {
    case null => Nil
    case w => w :: allStrings(expr)
}
```

It's elegant and awesome except that it had thrown a StackOverflow exception when I tried to load a huge dictionary file.

Now as far as I understand Scala supports tail recursion, so that function call couldn't possibly overflow the stack, probably compiler doesn't recognize it? So after some googling I tried @tailrec annotation to help the compiler out, but it said

```
error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
def allStrings(expr: => String): List[String] =
```

Am I understanding tail recursion wrong? How do I fix this code?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Scala can only optimise this if the last call is a call to the method itself.

Well, the last call is not to `allStrings`, it's actually to the `::` (cons) method.

A way to make this tail recursive is to add an accumulator parameter, for example:

```
def allStrings(expr: => String, acc: List[String] = Nil): List[String] =
  expr match {
    case null => acc
    case w => allStrings(expr, w :: acc)
  }
```

To prevent the accumulator leaking into the API, you can define the tail recursive method as a nested method:

```
def allStrings(expr: => String) = {
  def iter(expr: => String, acc: List[String]): List[String] =
    expr match {
      case null => acc
      case w => iter(expr, w :: acc)
    }
  iter(expr, Nil)
}
```

Comment: When copying my answer, you forgot the `@tailrec` annotation. This is not just an easy way to have the compiler confirm your expectations, it's also a useful hint to subsequent maintainers.

Comment: Kevin, I did not copy your answer, I was actually making edits when you posted. But you make a good point about the annotation, for which I've upvoted your answer, despite your snide remark :)

Comment: I was going to delete mine on seeing we'd answered simultaneously, but didn't after noticing that you'd used a default param instead of a nested method. You can appreciate how dubious it then looks when a subsequent edit then adds this alternative in your answer.

Answer (score 25):

It's not tail recursive (and can't ever be) because the final operation is not a recursive call to `allStrings`, it's a call to the `::` method.

The safest way to resolve this is with a nested method that uses an accumulator:

```
def allStrings(expr: => String) = {
  @tailrec
  def inner(expr: => String, acc: List[String]): List[String] = expr match {
    case null => acc
    case w => inner(expr, w :: acc)
  }
  inner(expr, Nil)
}
```

In this particular case, you could also lift the accumulator to a parameter on `allStrings`, give it a default value of `Nil`, and avoid the need for an inner method.  But that's not always possible, and it can't be called nicely from Java code if you're concerned about interop.